# Stretching the polygon layer into another polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, editing, spatial-adjustment

Is there a possibility to stretch the blue layer into the white one?

I would like to fit the districts (the blue layer) into the city (the white layer), but I don't have any idea how to do it with such different data.

[image]

Comment: You're looking for the Snap or Integrate tools. That or manual editing.

Answer (score 0):

To address this I think you should use [Spatial Adjustment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000030000000) to perform rubber sheeting:

> GIS data often comes from many sources. Inconsistencies between data
>   sources sometimes require you to perform additional work to integrate
>   a new dataset with the rest of your data. Some data is geometrically
>   distorted or rotated with respect to your base data.
>
> Within the editing environment, the spatial adjustment tools provide
>   interactive methods to align and integrate your data. Spatial
>   adjustment supports a variety of adjustment methods and will adjust
>   all editable data sources. It's often used when you've imported data
>   from another source, such as a CAD drawing. Some of the tasks you can
>   perform include converting data from one coordinate system to another,
>   correcting geometric distortions, aligning features along the edge of
>   one layer to features of an adjoining layer, and copying attributes
>   between layers. Since spatial adjustment operates within an edit
>   session, you can use existing editing functionality, such as snapping,
>   to enhance your adjustments.